# Make Singular Android Widget

Tags: android, widget, homescreen

I am developing and Android widget and I want that widget to be singular , which means if the user added my widget to his home screen he should not be able to add it again to his screen

Comment: Why would you want to restrict the user in that way, as a good rule of thumb, DON'T prevent your users from doing stuff that they want to do, or they will find another app that does it for them, help them and make things easy for them, that's how you keep and grow your userbase for your app :)

Comment: Using more than widget from my App may Cause massive damage for my application!

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround you could try to accomplish this:

1) Create a public static Integer variable in you AppWidgetProvider to keep track of the widget Id, set it to null initially

2) Create a configuration activity for the widget (instructions for that are here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring)

3) In your configuration activity, check the status of the variable in the provider. If a widget has already been created (the id is not equal to null), you can display a message to the user with an AlertDialog, and then set the result to cancelled.

Your code might look like this:

In your provider:

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static Integer widgetId;

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        //If the current widget has been deleted, set widget id to null again
        for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){
            if(widgetId == appWidgetIds[i]){
                widgetId = null;
            }
        }
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

In your configuration activity

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends Activity {
    public int appWidgetId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,  AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        if(MyAppWidgetProvider.widgetId != null){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Widget already created");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, resultValue);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            MyAppWidgetProvider.widgetId = appWidgetId;
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();   
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);      
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```